# Good Material 4 Learning Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

I' m totally inexperienced with MySQL.I have to use workbench.
Where can I learn? I don't have any text at all.
Do you have any suggestions?
I can't find anything linear on websites.

Comment: Do you know SQL?  Have you worked with any RDBMS before?

Comment: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: No, it's my frist time ever.
I'm attending the university and i hate to reverse the fault on others, but our teacher has never been there during the entire course.

Comment: Code Academy has a free, short series which could help you understand some of the basics. MySQL's official documentation is very good, in my opinion. Break whatever you're trying to do into smaller problems, and review past StackOverflow posts and/or ask good questions. http://sqlfiddle.com can help you practice.

Comment: After you are familiar with SQL syntax, [SQLZOO](https://sqlzoo.net/) is a good place to practice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com always help in all this tutorials.

For more details refer this page:  [MySQL Workbench Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html)